# Variable inside socket.on('connect') not updating

Tags: socket.io, react-hooks

This React with Socket.io.

```js
    [canPass, setCanPass] = useState(true)
    [example, setExample] = useState('')

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(socket !== ''){
            setCanPass(false)
            console.log(example)
            if(canPass){
                socket.on('connect', ()=>{
                    console.log(example)
                })
            }
        }
    },[socket, example])
```

- This code is inside of a Provider, so the variable "example" will change often.
- Initial value of "socket" is an empty string. After the socket is created, the effect will set the listener "connect".
- The flag "canPass" avoids setting the listener over and over any time the effect gets triggered.

**NOW THE PROBLEM IS:** Variable "example" updates normally inside of the Effect, but when the listener function is triggered (let's say server drops and reestablish, or user turn off and on wifi) variable "example" INSIDE of the listener function remains unchanged.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!!

**EDIT -> FIXED!**

I don't really understand why this question is not that frecuent as I expected. Ok, so, the thing is an event can link more than one listener, and each listener is an instance of the function, it means, it creates a separated scope and the variables inside wont update.

To fix it, I just added another effect, observing the changes of variable "example", ereasing the listener with the method removeAllListeners() and set it again with the new values of "example". And that's it.

Comment: Instead of adding "Edit - fixed" you could write an answer yourself and mark it as the answer. This might helper others more easily find an answer if they are experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @RonaldRink'd-fens' oh ok! thanks for the advice! Next time I will do it ~